# What is the maximum number of persons that may have shaken hands with everyone?

Tags: graph-theory

> A number $n\ge3$ of persons meet at a party, and some of them shake hands. It is known that at least one person does not shake hands with everybody (that is, maybe he/she shakes hands with someone, but not with everyone). What is the maximum number of persons that may have shaken hands with everyone?
>
> - $n/2$
> - $n-1$
> - $n-2$
> - None of the above

Hi. I am unsure about this question - I have answered $n - 1$, as we know one of the person doesn't shake hands.

Comment: If Bob didn't shake Joe's hand, then Joe didn't shake Bob's hand.

Answer (score 4):

There's at least one other person that the not-shaking-all person did not shake hands with, so $n-1$ cannot be reached. However, $n-2$ indeed *can* be reached: Pick two persons $A,B$ and let everybody shake all hands except that $A,B$ do not shake hands.

Answer (score 0):

If N-1 is correct, then there's just that one guy that didn't shake everyone's hand. But if he missed even 1 person, the minimum to "not shake everyone's" than that person didn't shake everyone's either. 
So we drop to N-2 to satisfy the statement.